Beginner in C#, stuck in a Loop and IF statement
Sorry I was being VERY unclear. ALL numbers from 1  and up to the entered number are being checked if they are evenly dividable with 3 and 7, so the if-statement and loop in this code does exactly what I want it to do.
But then if no numbers are..... Oh, I figured it out! Damn, I knew it would be stupid easy.
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num < 21)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No dividable numbers found.");
            }
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)

        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number " + i + " is evenly dividable with both 3 and 7.");

            }
        }
     


It's unclear what you're trying to do here. You've asked the user for a number, but then you're testing all positive integers up to and including that number. Regardless, the simplest approach for answering your question would be to declare a boolean before the for loop (e.g. bool numberNotDivisible = false;), add an else block to your divisibility check (... else { numberNotDivisible = true; }) and then use another if after the for loop to show the final message only if the boolean has not been set.

Shouldn't that be num % 3 == 0 && num % 7 == 0? (Your checking your counter, not that number.)

What's the "number" you are entering? You have 2 prime numbers (3 and 7); you won't get anywhere with a number that's less than 21.

Your line Console.WriteLine("Number cannot be evenly divided."); will always be printed since it's not part of the if-statement. Use if..else.

i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0 is equivalent to i % 21 == 0

Sorry yall, I understand the confusion. My post was really unclear.
@NeilT Cheers! And good job adding a solution to my code even if you didn't really make sense of it. :D

I'm not sure what the loop is for but to change when the last line is printed you'll need another if clause. This one working directly on num, not i. It also needs to be the opposite of your earlier check.
if (num % 3 != 0 || num % 7 != 0)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Number cannot be evenly divided (by both 3 and 7).");
    }


If you need to check if the user has entered a number that is not able to be evenly divided by 3 and 7, you do not need a for-loop. Here is an example code:.
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(input, out int num))
{
    if (num % 3 != 0 && num % 7 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number " + num + " is evenly divided with both 3 and 7.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number cannot be evenly divided.");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error in input data");
}

In this code, you enter an input, which is then parsed as a number. The code checks the conditions using an if statement, and if the conditions are not met, it gives you the appropriate message.
